# PlotDataItem.sigPointsClicked doesn't work

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

```
import tutorial4
from tutorial4 import *

def clicked(item,points):
    print("curve clicked")

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = TestApp()

pw3 = win.ui.graphicsView.plotItem
curve = pw3.plot(np.random.normal(size=100)*1e0, clickable=True)
curve.curve.setClickable(True)
curve.setPen('w')  ## white pen
curve.setShadowPen(pg.mkPen((70,70,30), width=6, cosmetic=True))
curve.sigPointsClicked.connect(clicked)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hello, i am trying using the sigPointsClicked on a plot, which i created using the **pyqtgraph**(in a GUI that i created with Qt Designer).

when i clicked on the graph, nothing happens - it doesn't call the "clicked" function.

do you have any idea why?

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1):

`sigPointsClicked` is only emitted when scatterplot points are clicked. You probably want `sigClicked` instead.

Comment: well, i tried sigClicked, but it dosen't send the points which the mouse clicked. so, there isn't a way to get the points with PlotDataItem?
Thanks, Guy

Comment: Have a look at `examples/crosshair.py` -- this makes use of a different signal that includes the position of the mouse click.